# VSCode - Settings Sync - Unable to write file EACCES

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I had problems syncing my VSCode configurations using the extension [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync).

[image: VSCode Settings Sync Output]

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, change `YOUR_USER` to the user name you are logged in.

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USER ~/.config
```